# bash arguments as variables

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, nagios

Hey I am working on a Nagios plugin which aims to permit complex comparations with perfdata.

The idea is to pass as argument a comparation string and then work with it to give the status.

```
check_vmstat «display» [-o «output vars»] [-w «warning expr.»] [-c «critical expr.»] -d «delay»
```

expressions are boolean expr. with variables names.    for example:

```
check_vmstat cpu_us,memory_free,memory_swpd -w (((cpu_us>80)&&(memory_free<20))||((memory_swpd>5)&&(memory_free<50))) -c *>90
```

also «display» and «output_variables» will use such nomenclature.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have to quote the conditions so they aren't evaluated in the current shell

option parsing left as an exercise:

```
warn='(((cpu_us>80)&&(memory_free<20))||((memory_swpd>5)&&(memory_free<50))) '
vmstat 1 2 | 
tail -n 1 | 
{ 
    read _ _ memory_swapd memory_free _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ cpu_us _ _ _
    eval "(( $warn )) && echo WARNING"
}
```